# Grafana Table Panel 'clickable' and use it to drill down to a more detailed view

Tags: events, grafana

Is it possible to have a Table Panel in Grafana, and when you click on a row, it shows a graph from another set of time series?

I see there is a feature request for it, but I'm not sure it's available yet
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/5481

> Looking for any suggestions on making the rows in a Table Panel
>   'clickable' and use it to drill down to a more detailed view (another
>   dashboard using Template variables). Currently displaying a summary of
>   several servers as rows in a Table Panel and we want to select an
>   individual row (i.e a server) to drill down to a more detailed
>   Dashboard.

Any ways to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature request you linked to is a duplicate of this [one](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3754) which links to this [Pull Request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/8738). The PR was recently merged so it is available now as a nightly build and will be included in the upcoming 5.0.0 release in September/October.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this also in 4.x by defining a link for a table column (in the `Column Styles` section under `Visualization`). The link can refer to another dashboard and embed current cell's value (or other cell in the same row) as a parameter.

For example the link Url can be: 
`/d/c9xaXx5Zz/tree-node?var-datasource=$datasource&var-interval_id=${__cell_1}&from=$__from&to=$__to&var-path=root`

In Grafana 6 or above you can preserve the time range filter using the `$__from` and `$__to` built-in vars.

The available built-in variables to access cell contents are not well documented, but they can be found by hovering over the (i) icon of the Url in the table panel.

More info on built-in vars: https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/#global-built-in-variables

Comment: I'd love to understand how you constructed that example Url so I can construct my own.  Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @doub1ejack I don't know if its well documented, just played a little bit around. Look at the url of the dashboard you want to link to and construct a url with proper variable names. Don't forget to prepend "var-" to each variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Drill Down Option can be used from **General** option from Grafana Dashboard.

[image]

Copy the link in the Url of the table which you want to show. Change the items in the variable part which is changing according to the need.It will be of format **var-name=value**

Comment: What version of Grafana is providing that? Version 7.3 isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The link URL works well if you are linking to another dashboard, but it does not work well if you are changing a variable on the same dashboard as it does not auto-refresh.

You can add JavaScript into the URL instead of a link.

```
javascript:$('a.variable-value-link').trigger('click'); $('span:contains(${__cell:raw})').closest('a').trigger('click');
```

The JavaScript only works for a single dropdown, it would have to be updated if there were multiple dropdowns. I worked on this quickly, so I am sure there is a better way to use JavaScript to change the variable. It basically opens the dropdown, finds the value from the current row and selects it.

Comment: I feel this is too hacky to have it in production.